# working with received json inside my asp.net mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

Usually when i want to convert a model object to a json object inside my asp.net mvc , i simple return my model object using JSONResult as follow:-

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term)
        {

          //code goes here...
            return Json(myobject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

which will serialize the model object into json format.. now i am working with a third party API that return json , the returned json have multiple formats one of them as follow:-

```
{"operation":{"name":"GET RESOURCES","result":{"status":"Success","message":"Resources fetched successfully"},"totalRows":2,"Details":[{"RESOURCE DESCRIPTION":"","RESOURCE NAME":"test resource","RESOURCE ID":"1","RESOURCE TYPE":"Windows","NOOFACCOUNTS":"1"},{"RESOURCE DESCRIPTION":"","RESOURCE NAME":"test resource123","RESOURCE ID":"301","RESOURCE TYPE":"Windows","NOOFACCOUNTS":"1"}]}}
```

now if  i want to read specific values from the returned json,,  can i use a built-in features inside asp.net for deserilazing json ?,, same as the return Json() used for serializing json or i need to use extra libraries such as json.net??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use JSON.NET. It is usually included into the project and latest ASP.NET MVC frameworks use it under the hood. JSON.NET is fast, flexible and popular.

But you can use built-in classes:

```
var javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var myClass = javascriptSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
```

If you want to do this with JSON.NET:

```
var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: why you recommend using JSON.NET ?